# Possible ways that seven passenger can find seats between 17 seats?

Tags: probability

I remember I was able to solve this form of questions in high school. But now I'm lost.

A bus has nine seats facing forward and eight seats backward. In how many ways can seven passengers be seated if two refuse to ride facing forward and three refuse to ride facing backward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We pick 2 places for the passengers that want to face backwards among the eight backward seats, in $8 \times 7$ ways. Then we pick three places for the forward preferrers among the 9 forward seats, in $9 \times 8 \times 7$ ways.

We are left with $7 - 2 - 3 = 2$ passengers who can sit on any of the remaining $17 - 5 = 12$ seats so we can pick those in $12 \times 11$ ways.

So we have $8 \times 7 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 12 \times 11$ total ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to place the 5 passengers with restrictions then the others

numbers of ways = 8*7*9*8*7*12*11 = 3 725 568

Answer (score 0):

Hint:-

There are $9$ front facing seats and 8 back facing seats.

Also,$3$ and $2$ passengers refuse to take back and front seats respectively.

So,now find out how the $3$ passengers in the front seats can interchange their seats in $9$ seats.

Similarly find it for the $2$ back passengers the number of ways to sit in the $8$ seats.

Also find the number of ways in which the remaining $2$ passengers can be seated in  the seats left after the $5$ passengers occupy their seats.